# Proving two variables are independent if $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

I am working through a measure-theory probability theory book and I have the following problem:

Suppose each of $X$ and $Y$ take on at most two values, $a$ and $b$. Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$.

I know that to show independence, I need to show that for any two Borel sets $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$, we have

$$P(\{ \omega \mid X(\omega) \in E_{1}\}) = P(\{\omega \mid Y(\omega) \in E_{2}\}), $$

but I have been having a lot of trouble doing so. I'm also not really sure where I would use the fact that they only take on two values.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your idea of how to show that two random variables $X,Y$ are independent is wrong. What really must be proved is that $P(X\in E_1,Y\in E_2)=P(X\in E_1)P( Y\in E_2)$ for any two Borel sets $E_1,E_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: when $a=0,b=1$ just observe thatb $XY=1$ iff $X=1$ and $Y=1$. This gives $P(X=1,Y=1)=P(X=1)P(Y=1)$ and you can prove independence fron this.

For the  general case take $X=\frac {X-a} {b-a}, V=\frac {Y-b} {a-b}$ and verify that $EUV=EUEV$. Since $U$ and $V$ take only the values $0$ and $1$ you can use the first case here.

Comment: I am sort of confused by what you mean when you mean "For the general case take $U = (X - a)/(b - a), V = (Y - b)/(a - b)$". Don't we need to show $X$ and $Y$ are independent ?

Comment: @joesx From the first case we see that $U$ and $V$ are independent. Since $X=a+(b-a)U$ and $Y=b+(a-b)V$ it follows that $X$ and $Y$ are also independent.

Comment: @joesx They correspond to the case  $a=0, b=1$ because they take only the values $0$ and $1$.